# How to add Jmeter .JMX file in Bitbucket

Tags: jmeter, bitbucket

I am new to Bitbucket and want to run jmeter script through Bitbucket. Here are the commands I have given for configurations:

pipelines:
default:
- step:
script:
- apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y openjdk-11-jre wget
- cd /opt && wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.5.tgz && tar xf apache-jmeter-5.5.tgz
- cd apache-jmeter-5.5/bin
- ./jmeter -n -t "Login.jmx"

However, I am getting below error on the last line:
"An error occurred: The file /opt/apache-jmeter-5.5/bin/Login.jmx doesn't exist or can't be opened"

I would like to know how can I give JMX file path as I have put it on root. I am assuming it is expected to be placed inside jmeter/bin folder? But how?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to have this `Login.jmx` script, my expectation is that you have it somewhere in [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) repository and your Bitbucket pipeline [clones the repository](https://bitbucket.org/blog/disabling-clones-in-pipelines-steps) before the step where you're [installing JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation)

So the options are in:

1. Copy your `Login.jmx` file from the cloned repository folder to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation

   ```
   cp $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/Login.jmx /opt/apache-jmeter-5.5/bin
   ```
2. Or point JMeter to use Login.jmx from the cloned repo's folder

   ```
   ./jmeter -n -t $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/Login.jmx
   ```

More information: [Variables and secrets](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, that sorted the issue. Can you please also suggest how can I test jmeter reporting inside Bitbucket? Thanks in advance!